# Implementing nested if-then-else tests

Tags: conditionals, ifthenelse

I would like to implement the following processsing for each row of my data, which is read with `datatool`:

```
if ( (\No = 5 and \B=11111) OR (\No = 5 and \B=22222) ):
  \inserpageA
else if ( (\No = 5) AND (\B not 11111) AND (\B not 22222) ): 
  \inserpageB
else: 
  \No \hspace{1cm} \B  \hspace{5cm} \A
```

My code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Acol, Bcol, NoCol
Ax,Bxxxx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,11111,5
Ax,B,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,22222,5
Ax,Bxxxx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,33333,5
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{mydata}{test.csv}
\newcommand{\inserpageA}[2]{%
\subsubsection*{AAA}
\newpage
}
\newcommand{\inserpageB}[2]{%
\subsubsection*{BBB}
\newpage
}
\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata}{\A=Acol, \B=Bcol, \No=NoCol}%
{%
 \No \hspace{1cm} \B  \hspace{3cm}  \A

}%

\end{document}
```

Please show how to implement the above rule. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. I propose two solutions, one using `xifthen`, the other using `expl3`. It would also be doable with `ifthen` and functions from `datatool`.

Note that for tests on `\B`, I used string comparison because the contents is not always a number, contrary to `\No`. I replaced one `2222` with `22222` in your logical expression (looks like a mistake in your question?).

I implemented the logical tests as you wrote them, but they could be simplified (the `\No` = 5 test could be factored out).

## Using `xifthen`

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Acol, Bcol, NoCol
Ax,Bxxxx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,11111,5
Ax,B,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,22222,5
Ax,Bxxxx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,33333,5
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{mydata}{test.csv}

\newcommand{\inserpageA}{%
  \subsubsection*{AAA}
  \newpage
}
\newcommand{\inserpageB}{%
  \subsubsection*{BBB}
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata}{\A=Acol, \B=Bcol, \No=NoCol}%
{%
  \ifthenelse{\(\cnttest{\No}{=}{5}\AND \equal{\B}{11111}\)\OR
              \(\cnttest{\No}{=}{5}\AND \equal{\B}{22222}\)}%
    {\inserpageA}%
    {\ifthenelse{\cnttest{\No}{=}{5}\AND
                 \NOT\equal{\B}{11111}\AND
                 \NOT\equal{\B}{22222}}%
       {\inserpageB}%
       {\No\hspace{1cm}\B \hspace{5cm}\A\par}%
    }%
}%

\end{document}
```

## Using `expl3`

Maybe you'll find the `expl3` way more readable. Contrary to `xifthen`, boolean expressions for `l3prg` (the `expl3` module for these things) use standard precedence rules for `&&` and `||` (logical AND and logical OR, respectively), which is nice.

Note that spaces are ignored between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`. If you need a space there, use `~` or `\space`. `~` may be ignored as usual after a control word, for instance the `~` in `\B ~` is ignored, but `\B \space` will insert a space token when `\space` is expanded (it is a macro expanding to an explicit space token).

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv}
Acol, Bcol, NoCol
Ax,Bxxxx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,11111,5
Ax,B,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,22222,5
Ax,Bxxxx,1
Ay,By,3
A1,B22,2
A2,B44,4
A3,33333,5
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{mydata}{test.csv}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \lfortiProcessOneRow { }
  {
    \bool_if:nTF
      { % The parentheses below are not necessary, because && has higher
        % priority than || in expl3 (l3prg) boolean expressions.
        ( \int_compare_p:nNn { \No } = { 5 } && \str_if_eq_p:Vn \B {11111} ) ||
        ( \int_compare_p:nNn { \No } = { 5 } && \str_if_eq_p:Vn \B {22222} )
      }
      { \inserpageA }
      {
        \bool_if:nTF
          { \int_compare_p:nNn { \No } = { 5 } &&
            ! \str_if_eq_p:Vn \B {11111}       &&
            ! \str_if_eq_p:Vn \B {22222}
          }
          { \inserpageB }
          { \No \hspace{1cm} \B \hspace{5cm} \A \par }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\inserpageA}{%
  \subsubsection*{AAA}
  \newpage
}
\newcommand{\inserpageB}{%
  \subsubsection*{BBB}
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach*{mydata}{\A=Acol, \B=Bcol, \No=NoCol}{\lfortiProcessOneRow}

\end{document}
```

## Output of both examples

[image: Output]

Comment: super. Thank so much. I tested add "\ifthenelse{\(\cnttest{\No}{=}{1}\)}%
   {\inserpageA} before \ifthenelse{\(\cnttest{\No}{=}{5}\AND \equal{\B}{11111}\)\OR
              \(\cnttest{\No}{=}{5}\AND \equal{\B}{22222}\)}%" ..but don't work. How can i add more condition: If \No = 1, insert page A. Thanks

Comment: You are missing a braced group for the “else” part. Look at the [`xifthen` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xifthen/xifthen.pdf) page 2. The syntax is `\ifthenelse{〈test expression〉}{〈true code〉}{〈false code〉}`. Also, you don't need the parentheses here (`(` and `)`) but when you use them in an `xifthen` test, they must be preceded by a backslash, as in `\(` or `\)`.

Comment: I added an `expl3`-based solution, you may find it easier to work with. Look for *Boolean expressions* in [interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) for documentation on `l3prg` (`expl3`) boolean expressions.