# Use xifthen: how set \cnttest not equal number

Tags: xifthen

i read user manual of [`xifthen`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) package.

But i don't find "Not equal" command.
How can i set below rule:

```
\ifthenelse \cnttest{\Var} equal A: Do newcommand AAA
\ifthenelse \cnttest{\Var} equal B: Do newcommand BBB
\ifthenelse \cnttest{\Var} equal C: Do newcommand CCC
\ifthenelse \cnttest{\Var} not equal A, AND not equal B, AND not equal C: Do newcommand ABC
```

And other Rule is below:

```
  \ifthenelse \cnttest{\Var} not equal A, AND not equal B, AND not equal C: Do newcommand ABC
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\ifthenelse` macro takes three arguments:

```
\ifthenelse{<test>}{<code for true>}{<code for false>}
```

Thus you can simply nest the calls:

```latex
\ifthenelse{\cnttest{\Var}{=}{1}}{Case 1}{%
  \ifthenelse{\cnttest{\Var}{=}{2}}{Case 2}{%
    \ifthenelse{\cnttest{\Var}{=}{3}}{Case 3}{%
       {Case not 1, not 2, not 3}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Comment: thank, how can i set \ifthenelse{\cnttest \Var equal Not 1, do case A1 ? \ifthenelse{\cnttest \Var equal  NOT 1 AND NOT 3 do case A13...?

Comment: @latexforti It would be better if you tell what’s your real aim.

Comment: Thanks. i have datatools: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505127/implementing-nested-if-then-else-tests/505209#505209 and \var is range (0-100). If var is not 0,50,100 then call newcommand XXX